# Get Local Taxonomies using Repository.GetTaxonomiesOwl()

Tags: 2013-sp1, tom.net

I am building a category/Keyword hierarchy xml file on publishing a page. And I don't want to loop through the categories and keywords to avoid performance issue.

So, I am using `Repository.GetTaxonomiesOwl()` in TOM.NET for a repository to get the Taxonomies data in [OWL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-xmlsyntax/) format. and applying xslt on this to get the xml.

`Repository.GetTaxonomiesOwl()` returns all the taxonomies (Local + Shared) for that Repository and doesn't have any info about taxonomy owning repository.

The returned element for a keyword looks like below:
    
        Level1 - Test Keyword1
        Level1 - Test Keyword1
        
        false
        true

My requirement is to get only local taxonomies for the repository.

My questions are, is there any way to :

1. Filter the taxonomy results, which are local to the repository(Publication)?
2. Include owning repository attribute in the results? so that I can filter the results based on that attribute.

Comment: Hi Saurabh - can you share the filter and the response?

Comment: Don't you see a node formatted something like: tcmt:isRoot

Comment: Yeah Mark, But the tcmt:isRoot specifies if the keyword is a root keyword in the keyword hierarchy within a category, as a keyword can have keywords as children. It doesn't say anything about the owning repository of the keyword.

Comment: TaxonomiesOwl is quite heavy filter is the any reason why you don't use `Repository.GetListTaxonomies(TaxonomiesFilter filter)` or `Repository.GetTaxonomies(TaxonomiesFilter filter)`?

Comment: I want to fetch one xml from tridion, which contains categories and keywords. So that i can apply a xslt to produce another xml file. `Repository.GetListTaxonomies(TaxonomiesFilter filter)` returns only categories. So I am not using it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want using a two-step process:

1. Select all local Categories in a given Repository (e.g. using
   `Repository.GetListCategories()` and a bit of LINQ to filter out
   local ones).
2. Call `Repository.GetTaxonomiesOwl(TaxonomiesOwlFilter)`
   overload to pass in a `TaxonomiesOwlFilter` with property
   `RootCategories` set to the Categories you selected in step 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rick. But I need localize info for both categories and keywords(inside the categories) as well and it seems `GetTaxonomiesOwl` doesn't return that info.